# view.calculateExtent returning [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3.18.2.
My map is olMap and my view is olView.
I want to get the extent of the visible map on the screen.

```
olView.getCenter() = [2142126.3712395,-4085536.2324793]
olView.getZoom() = 16
olView.getResolution() = 2.388657133911758
olMap.getSize() = [1906,904]
olView.calculateExtent(olMap.getSize()) = [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]
```

Why is this not returning a proper extent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sleeping on it, considering the feedback here and some more experimenting I have found the cause of the problem: The coordinates are coming from an AJAX call which is returning strings. I call

```
olView.setCenter([x, y])
```

when x and y are strings the map view changes to the correct center position, but then doesn't function properly. Changing the call to

```
olView.setCenter([parseFloat(x), parseFloat(y)])
```

makes the map work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you shouldn't have any problem in getting the extent of map as the code seems correct.My map is defined as map and map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize()).I was able to get extent.[You can see from the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwvvF.png)

Comment: I have tested in IE11, FireFox and Chrome using both my custom build and the full build of OL3.18.2 and get the same result. NaN

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of getting on with the job I calculated the extent myself:

```
var center = olView.getCenter();
var res = olView.getResolution();
var pxSize = olMap.getSize();
var cx = parseFloat(center[0]);
var cy = parseFloat(center[1]);
var dx = res * pxSize[0] / 2;
var dy = res * pxSize[1] / 2;
var extent = [cx - dx, cy - dy, cx + dx, cy + dy];
```

olView.getCenter() is returning an array of strings, hence the parseFloat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsFiddle of a map similar to yours (using OSM as basemap).  calculateExtent() appears to be working correctly http://jsfiddle.net/e969kjro/1/

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<button id="myButton" onclick="test()">Click Me</button>

var view = new ol.View({
    center: [2142126.3712395,-4085536.2324793],
    zoom: 16
    })

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: view
});

window.test = function () {
    alert(view.calculateExtent(map.getSize()));
}
```